# How to use case statement in where condition in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

```
SELECT DY,ME,NONME 
FROM ( 
    SELECT LEVEL, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+ROWNUM,'DAY') DY , 0 ME, 2 NONME
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10
) 
WHERE ?
```

If the condition is `(ME < NONME)` then `not in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')`

when `(ME> NONME)` then `not in ('FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY')`

How to use?

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` _clause_.

Comment: By the way, it's better to use abbreviated names (if only to avoid the need for trimming whitespace) and specify a language, e.g. `to_char(sysdate+rownum, 'DY', 'nls_date_language=English')`

Answer (score 0):

```
(
  (ME<NONME and .... not in (...)) OR
  (ME>NONME and .... not in (...))
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or [how this code answers the question improves its long-term value](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your test data is as follows:

```
select * from tab;

M N DY      
- - --------
A B FRIDAY  
A B SATURDAY
A B SUNDAY  
B A FRIDAY  
B A SATURDAY
B A SUNDAY
```

You need to evaluate *implication* `A --> B`  which can be rewritten as `NOT A  OR B`

Using this rule your query is

```
select * from tab
where 
-- (ME < NONME) --> not in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')
(not (ME < NONME) or DY not in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY'))  AND
-- (ME> NONME) -->  not in ('FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY')
(not (ME > NONME) or DY not in ('FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY'))
;
```

giving

```
M N DY      
- - --------
A B FRIDAY  
B A SUNDAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query containing case-insensitive `NOT regexp_like()` with parenthesed `AND` operators and an `OR` operator combining those expressions :

```
WITH T AS
(
  SELECT LEVEL, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + LEVEL, 'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') DY, 0 ME, 2 NONME
    FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
)
SELECT *
  FROM T
 WHERE ( NOT regexp_like(dy,'sat|sun','i') AND ME < NONME ) 
    OR ( NOT regexp_like(dy,'sat|fri','i') AND ME > NONME )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64a5cd10b80041f93df60a7ab7846879)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If your are keen to use `case..when` statement then it should be done as following:

```
.....
Where case 
      when ME < NONME and dy not in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')
      then 1 
      When ME > NONME and DY not in ('FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY') 
      then 1
      end = 1
```

Cheers!!